# Preserving run_list while running knife bootstrap over a node which already has a run list associated with it

Tags: chef-infra, knife

Is there any way I can run knife bootstrap command with a new cookbook/recipe over a node, such that the older run_list of the node is preserved and the new cookbook/recipe gets appended to the existing run_list?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, but you can use the other `knife node` commands to manipulate the run list and then use `knife ssh` to run chef-client.

Comment: Knife node edit would allow me to append/add new cookbook/recipe to existing run list , but running the chef-client using knife ssh would lead to execution of complete run_list over the node. I would like to run only the new cookbook/recipe and not the entire run_list and at the same time do not want the existing run_list  to vanish.

Comment: You can kind of do that with `-o` for override run lists, but that comes with a whole host of footnotes of its own. In general, this isn't how Chef works, it is expected that you will build run lists based on what a node is for, and that those recipes will be idempotent.